# Symfony Login - User / Admin

Tags: php, security, symfony, symfony-security

I would like connect my Admin when I access to /admin or with the login form.

But something's wrong, I can't access to the ROLE_ADMIN.

(Everything's fine with the ROLE_USER, maybe I miss somethings for the Admin  ?)

There's the security.yml file :

security:

```
providers:

    our_db_provider:
                entity:
                    class: WebAwardsBundle:User
                    property: username
                    # if you're using multiple entity managers
                    # manager_name: customer
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin:
                    password: $2y$13$aabu98fd.l60phldkU.WAeDwgzqiv1IcaF.EndURJuAhGllFgzTv.
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt
        WebAwardsBundle\Entity\User:
                    algorithm: bcrypt
firewalls:

    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        #http_basic: ~
        #pattern:    ^/
        #provider: our_db_provider
        form_login:
          login_path: login
          check_path: login


        # Log out user
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

There's the SecurityController.php file :

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/admin", name="admin_action")
 */
public function adminAction()
{
    return new Response('<html><body>Admin page!</body></html>');
}}
```

And this is the login.htm.twig file :

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
<div>CONNECTEZ-VOUS</div>
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use more than one provider, you need configure them in chain

```
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [our_db_provider, in_memory]
```

You can read about multiple providers [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html)

Comment: Yes ! Thank's for that ! @Vladimir